# I am receiving a Server error on on the controller on my ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that I have created. The data displays fine however I get an error which you can see below:

[image]

I have created the views and controllers fine however on 2 out of the 5 views / index there is an issue when performing a search via the controller I get an error.

Below is the search functionality I have added to the controller

```
 public AppSupportEntities db = new AppSupportEntities();

        // GET: Servers
        public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
        {
            if (searchBy == "NAME")
            {
                return View(db.Servers.Where(x => x.NAME.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList());
            }
            else
            {
                return View(db.Servers.Where(x => x.DESCRIPTION.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList());
            }
        }
```

This is the search functionality added to the index page on the view

```
@model IEnumerable<ADSTrepo.Models.Server>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Server List</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Server", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <b>Search By:</b> @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Name") <text>Name</text>
        @Html.RadioButton("searchBy", "Description") <text>Description</text>
        @Html.TextBox("Search")<input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NAME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr>

            <td colspan="2"> No rows match the search criteria please try again</td>

        </tr>
    }

    else
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NAME)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DESCRIPTION)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated I must be missing something obvious however the views and controllers seem fine and the same as the others that are working

Comment: What does `db.Servers.Where(x => x.NAME.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList()` return? If it's a string collection, then results which return a single value will make the `View()` method think you're asking it to load a specific view.

Comment: Hi @TiesonT. This should return the start of the NAME and if the search is null to return all values in the list, works in 2 of my controllers. Not sure what the issue is here as it seems the same as the others that are working

Comment: add full controller class

Comment: What is the name of the controller and action?

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved now. The searchy by name in my controller was different to whats in my view.